# You are stuck in a room with only three doors you have to get out of there

Tags: riddle

You are stuck in a room with only three doors you have to get out of there
Behind the first door there is a killer joker

Behind the second door there are three lions who haven't eaten anything from the last three months

And Behind the last door there is a rouge ninja and he will kill anyone he sees

Which door would you choose

Answer (score -3):

I believe the answer is:

> The second door.

Because:

> No one can survive for three months without eating!

Comment: Plenty of mammals do by hibernating

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Please remember to hide your answers via the `>!` tag. Thank you!